# AT command get caller number when already in another call

Tags: call, at-command, clip, ring, sim900

I am using SIM900A card and currently working on AT commands.
I am trying to get caller number when I am already in another call.
In theory I should get "CLIP+ number", this only works when I am not in communication.
During a call, when someone calls me, I get "RING". I want the number of the second caller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer, I thought someone might benefit from it.
I actually used AT+CLCC which show my calls log. From this log I extracted the number using substring.
This document helped me a lot : https://www.usr.cn/Down/Development/USR-GPRS-AT_Commnad_Set_V5.00.pdf